# "Cannot deserialize instance of" from outside API

Tags: java, json

I am trying make online cantor. i need to get table with currency value from outside API, exactly from that page : http://api.nbp.pl/api/exchangerates/tables/A?format=json
I want to get answer in Currency class. Could someone help me with that task ?

```
@Service
public class CurrentFromNBPImpl implements CurrentFromNBP {

@Override
public Currency getValueOfCurrency(String currencyCode) throws WrongCurrencyCode {

    Currency currency = null;

    try {
        URL url = new URL("http://api.nbp.pl/api/exchangerates/tables/A?format=json");
        HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        connection.setRequestMethod("GET");
        connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");

        if (connection.getResponseCode() == 404)
            throw new WrongCurrencyCode(currencyCode);

        InputStreamReader inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream());
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(inputStreamReader);
        String jsonOutput = bufferedReader.readLine();

        connection.disconnect();

        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        Currency list = objectMapper.readValue(jsonOutput, Currency.class);
        System.out.println(list);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    assert false;
    return currency;
}
}



@Data
public class Currency {

    @JsonProperty("table")
    private String table;
    @JsonProperty("no")
    private String no;
    @JsonProperty("effectiveDate")
    private String effectiveDate;
    @JsonProperty("rates")
    private List<Rate> rates = null;

}
@Data
public class Rate {

    @JsonProperty("currency")
    private String currency;
    @JsonProperty("code")
    private String code;
    @JsonProperty("mid")
    private Double mid;

    }
```

log: 
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: Cannot deserialize instance of `com.kolej.bartosz.challenge.domain.Currency` out of START_ARRAY token
 at [Source: (String)"[{"table":"A","no":"062/A/NBP/2019","effectiveDate":"2019-03-28","rates":[{"currency":"bat (Tajlandia)","code":"THB","mid":0.1202},{"currency":"dolar amerykański","code":"USD","mid":3.8202},{"currency":"dolar australijski","code":"AUD","mid":2.7098},{"currency":"dolar Hongkongu","code":"HKD","mid":0.4867},{"currency":"dolar kanadyjski","code":"CAD","mid":2.8461},{"currency":"dolar nowozelandzki","code":"NZD","mid":2.6006},{"currency":"dolar singapurski","code":"SGD","mid":2.8179},{"currency":"eu"[truncated 1616 chars]; line: 1, column: 1]

Comment: What is unclear here? You said Jackson your JSON will be a single `Currency` object, but it isn't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this

```
ArrayList<Currency> list = new ArrayList<>();
list = objectMapper.readValue(data, new TypeReference<ArrayList<Currency>>() {});
```

Comment: Works perfect ! Thx.

Answer (score 1):

Your json object that you want to deserialize is a jsonArray. You need to deserialize into a list of `Currency`, instead of a `Currency`.

Comment: List<Currency> list = (List<Currency>) objectMapper.readValue(jsonOutput, Currency.class);

i tried do it like that but still same problem could u give me example how to make it?